# successive keys in an rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way to combine successive keys by two into an array in an rdd?

lets say the rdd is:

> (0,0) (0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3)

result:

```
arr1 = Array((0,0), (0,0), (0,1), (1,1))
arr2 = Array((0,2), (0,3), (1,2) ,(1,3))
RDD[Array[(Int,Int)]]= arr1,arr2....
```

Comment: question is unclear - what does "combine successive keys by two" mean? How does that related to the example result?

Comment: Did you have an attempt that we can help you refine?

Comment: I was thinking something like a reduce statement where it combines not the same keys but the ones that differ by one.

Comment: so I want keys 0 and 1 to merge into one array and keys 2,3 to merge into another array in an rdd

Comment: Oh, when you say "keys", do you mean the _right-hand_ side of these tuples? Because those are usually referred to as the _values_, not keys - Spark assumes an `(a, b)` tuple has the form (key, value), i.e. `groupByKey` operation would group by `a`.

Comment: I can change that but yes i want something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide the "keys" (in this case, the right-hand side of the tuples) by 2 and group by the result - since these are `Int`s, the division would result in an `Int` as well, which means odd numbers would produce the same result as the preceding even number, giving you the result you're after:

```
val result: RDD[Iterable[(Int, Int)]] = rdd.groupBy { case (_, k) => k / 2 }.values

result.foreach(println)
// CompactBuffer((0,0), (0,0), (0,1), (1,1))
// CompactBuffer((0,2), (0,3), (1,2), (1,3)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with aggregatebykey or something else since groupby is expensive op

Comment: `groupBy` is only more expensive than its alternatives if the end result shouldn't be the "group" (i.e. an collection of results matching same key) but a reduced result (e.g. the sum of these results). In those cases, grouping before reducing the results may be expensive due to higher memory usage, larger records being shuffled etc. In this case, however, you can replace the `groupBy` with `aggregateByKey` with an aggregation function that collects all values into a collection - but you won't end up with something less expensive.